# Как в CSS изменить свойства текстового узла?

Tags: html, css

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Login</button>
```

Как мне тут менять свойства самого слова "Login"? Больше сделать его, или меньше. К какому селектору обращаться?

Comment: btn-block . Либо нацепите свой

Comment: А какие свойства необходимо изменить? Обычно достаточно обращения "к родителю".

Comment: @smellyshovel хочу его больше сделать и цвет поменять

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич обращайтесь к элементу. Цвет меняется свойством `color`, а размер текста - `font-size`. Получать доступ к TextNode, мало того, что не представляется возможным, в данном случае еще и излишне.

Comment: button[value='Login']

Comment: @smellyshovel понял. Спасибо

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич я в ответ напишу, пожалуй.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS не предоставляет возможности получить доступ к текстовому узлу (TextNode). Более того, это даже является излишним и совершенно ненужным, потому как все параметры текста внутри определенного элемента регулируются изменением свойств самого элемента.

Изменить цвет текста элемента можно при помощи свойства `color`, а его размер - при помощи свойства `font-size`.

Answer (score 1):

Но варианты есть! Т.е. можно скрыть одно и вывести другое заменив наполнение.

```css
button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .2rem 1rem;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

button:hover span::before {
  visibility: visible;
}

span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  r: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: "Привет!";
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button"><span>test</span></button>
```

Comment: Тут в вопросе не совсем об этом речь идет. Человек просто думал, что, для того, чтобы изменять параметры **текста**, нужно обратиться непосредственно к **тексту**, а не к элементу, который его содержит. И спрашивал, как это сделать.

Comment: Да изначально  вроде не так было написано, принято.

Comment: Ну, значит, я телепат, раз угадал, что автор вопроса имел в виду :)